# About the laravel eloquent model

Tags: laravel

The `laravel` API document: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::first()` description that:

```
Model|Builder|null first(array $columns = array('*'))

Execute the query and get the first result.
Parameters
array   $columns    
Return Value
Model|Builder|null
```

I can't understand the mean of the return value, In which case it will return Model and In which case it will return Builder?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? My documentation (for v4.2.12) states `@return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|static|null`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have used eloquent model for retrieving first record it return response in Model, and not sure about builder but when you retrieve records using builder it return builder object.

for example, consider we have states table and we are going to retrieve first record using two different method

1) Query Builder

```
$state_builder = DB::table("states")->first();
```

2) Eloquent Model

```
$state_eloquent = State::first();
```

you can check the difference between both response, and when no record found it will return null.

[image]